# Building reproducible reactJS application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I'm new with reactJS and I have to make some changes in an existing project.

I have to build an application with yarn and an already existing yarn.lock file.
Before making some changes, I would like to make sure that I can build the application just as it is now.

I've installed modules with 'yarn install'. --> Ok
I build the application with 'yarn build' --> Ok

BUT, the generated files don't have the same size as the one previously generated.

I thought that the purpose of yarn.lock files was to have reproducible build.

If I don't use the same nodeJS or the yarn version as the previous developer, can it affect the output?
Is there any other things that can influence the output?

Thanks